# Scrollbar not visible in on particular devices in openui5 application

Tags: sapui5

I am wondering how is it possible that when I am running openui5 application on different devices, it behaves differently on devices with viewing the vertical scrollbar - that's what I need to solve.

I have devices:

- zebra TC510K with 6.1.0 android version and on this device, the scrollbar is **not visible**.(I want it to be visible)
- computer and other mobile devices such as PM80 with android 5.0.2, or xperia z1 comp. with android 5.1.1 the scroll bar **is visible** as it is supossed to be.

[image][image]

Code I use:

```
<ScrollContainer id= "scrollCont" vertical="true" focusable="true" height="100%" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
                <Table
                    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding"
                    width="auto"
                    enableBusyIndicator="true"
                    includeItemInSelection="true"
                    items="">
                    <columns></columns>
                    <items>
                    </items>
                </Table>
                <Toolbar class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" id="idAssetListsPageTerminator">

                    <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <Title text=""
                           level="H3">
                    </Title>
                    <ToolbarSpacer/>

                </Toolbar>
            </ScrollContainer>
```

So inside ScrollContainer there are some things... property vertical is set to true. I tried adding this to the css but without positive result:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;!important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;!important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;!important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);!important;
    border-radius: 10px;!important;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;!important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;!important;
    background-color: #ffffff;!important;
}
```

also I tried this but without any result:

```
#scrollCont { overflow-x: scroll;  !important;
    overflow: scroll;!important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;!important;}
```

Could you suggest any solution?

Comment: I had a very similar issue recently (scrollbar was not visible in IE/Edge) and the root cause was a change inside Fiori theme

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible in newer UI5 versions? If yes, please create an issue on Github https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new